# Edit text of .ePub file programmatically in iOS/Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, epub

I have an eBook in a .epub format that I need to have integrated functionality in iOS to do the following:

1. Allow the user to physically write their name in the ebook.
2. Allow the user to physically sign their name in the ebook.
3. Allow the user to save the modified ebook locally on their device.

I have used the following SDK/Lib but not able to resolve my issue please guide me if anyone know how to do it.Remember i am not asking any type of software that can provide me this functionality this is totally about programming for iOS

- [AePubReader](https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader)
- [VikatanEpubReader](https://github.com/premkumarmsc/VikatanEpubReader)
- [ssziparchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)
- [Objective-Zip](https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip)
- [KFEpubKit](https://github.com/ricobeck/KFEpubKit)
- [calibre-ios-reader-applications](https://github.com/Philantrop/calibre-ios-reader-applications)
- [readium/SDKLauncher-iOS](https://github.com/readium/SDKLauncher-iOS)

Above all my most important task is to edit the writer/creator/author name of ePub file

Comment: If you figure out how to do this, you might be rich. The signing is easy, it's the saving that is death. You can save temporarily using LocalStorage, but that isn't permanent... And this isn't about programming iOS if you are using an ePub: it's about Javascript...

Comment: But i want to make an iOS application for this

Comment: Ah I see. Have you checked out Readium SDK? Readium.org